Assignin lists as elements of CUDF DataFrame
While using Pandas, I can add lists as elements without issues, as in
import pandas as pd

A = {"cls": "A"}
B = {"cls": "B"}
C = {"cls": ["A", "B"]}

df = pd.DataFrame([A,B,C])
type(df.iloc[2]["cls"])   # Returns `list`

But cudf.DataFrame do not accept a List. As we can see here:
import cudf
cu_df = cudf.DataFrame([A, B, C])

Fails with ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'list' object
We can see if we do not add C, it work.
import cudf
cu_df = cudf.DataFrame([A, B])

(no error)
Trying to convert from a regular pandas dataframe, also do not works
cu_df = cudf.DataFrame(df)

(fails with the same ArrowTypeError)
Any ideas in how to circumvent this?

Have you tried converting list into string?

After reading some documentation and this GitHub issue, it says

list operations are somewhat limited, and a column of lists can't be
treated the same as a column of ndarrays in Pandas.

Thus, you might try to convert the list into string:
A = {"cls": "A"}
B = {"cls": "B"}
C = {"cls": str(["A", "B"])}

and use it in cudf:
df = pd.DataFrame([A, B, C])
cu_df = cudf.DataFrame(df)

if that does not help, as mentioned on same issue:

explode each list column into a flat column, perform the binary
operation, then construct a list column back from the result


The problem in explod the column in flat column is that I don't know, before hand which size of list I will take, neither the amount of elements. I know that internally it´s very hard to cuda operation to handle a list of unknown size since it will not be able to correctly align or coalesce. Convert to string isn't a valid option, but exploding the column in multiple columns may be the only solution.
